# I have 3 errors running this code with \toprule and \midrule in a table... If include booktabs package in my preamble, I have 9 errors

Tags: tables, booktabs

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Zeros e pesos para quadratura de Gauss-Legendre}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccc}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{n = 5} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{n = 10} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{n = 15} \\
    \midrule
    $x_{i}$       & $w_{i}$           &  $x_{i}$           &  $w_{i}$          &  $x_{i}$          & $w_{i}$             \\
-0.906179845938664& 0.236926885056189 & -0.973906528517172 & 0.0666713443086882& -0.987992518020485& 0.0307532419961175 \\
-0.538469310105683& 0.478628670499366 & -0.865063366688985 & 0.149451349150581 & -0.937273392400706& 0.0703660474881079 \\ 
4.143437923020e-17& 0.568888888888889 & -0.679409568299024 & 0.219086362515983 & -0.848206583410427& 0.107159220467172  \\
0.538469310105683 & 0.478628670499367 & -0.433395394129247 & 0.269266719309996 & -0.72441773136017 & 0.139570677926154  \\
0.906179845938664 & 0.236926885056189 & -0.148874338981631 & 0.295524224714753 & -0.570972172608539& 0.166269205816994  \\
      -           &       -                 &  0.148874338981631 & 0.295524224714753 & -0.394151347077564& 0.186161000015562  \\
      -           &       -                 &  0.433395394129247 & 0.269266719309996 & -0.201194093997434& 0.198431485327111  \\
      -           &       -                 &  0.679409568299025 & 0.219086362515982 &  2.99577686686e-17&  0.202578241925561  \\
      -           &       -             &  0.865063366688984 & 0.149451349150581 &  0.201194093997435&  0.198431485327112  \\
      -           &       -                 &  0.973906528517172 & 0.0666713443086877&  0.394151347077563&  0.186161000015561  \\
      -           &       -                 &         -          &        -          &  0.570972172608539&  0.166269205816994  \\
      -           &       -                 &         -          &        -          &  0.72441773136017 &  0.139570677926154  \\
      -           &       -                 &         -          &        -          &  0.848206583410427&  0.107159220467171  \\
      -           &       -                 &         -          &        -          &  0.937273392400706&  0.0703660474881083 \\
      -           &       -                 &         -          &        -          &  0.987992518020486&  0.0307532419961175 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\label{table:zerosPesosQuad} % is used to refer this table in the text 
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're missing ``\\`` in the final row, before `\bottomrule`.

Comment: Add ``\\`` before `\bottomrule`, that should help. As well, please, enclose at least the minus signs of the negative numbers and the equalities in the top rule in `$...$` to make it real math, like `$-$` and `n = 10`.