# Exactly 27 errors?

Tags: errors, packages, fun

Just for fun.

In this question [I have 3 errors running this code with \toprule and \midrule in a table... If include booktabs package in my preamble, I have 9 errors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149608/i-have-3-errors-running-this-code-with-toprule-and-midrule-in-a-table-if-in) OP triples number of errors by adding a package. Is it possible  to add another package to obtain exactly 27 errors from her code?

Comment: To be useful for others in the future I think we should make it as a package that can generate variable number `n` of errors where `n` is any real (yes, it is not a typo) number.

Comment: @DonutE.Knot :-) It will be too easy. Generating such a file which  adds n errors to everything is not a challenge, but finding an existing  one, made for other purposes but strangely interacting with existing errors - probably yes.

Comment: `\let\br\bottomrule
\def\bottomrule{\br\br\br\br\br\br\br\br\br\br\br\br\br}`

Comment: Of course the package should conform to your requirement as well.

Comment: I don’t want to spoil the fun, but I’m afraid being well-aware that it’s not an adeßuate question for tex.sx doesn’t make it a valid question. Perhaps you could discuss this question in [chat]?

Comment: @StiffJokes I was blind... REAL?! I have not SUCH imagination.